# Bidirectional gRPC stream implementation in go

Tags: go, grpc

I'm looking at a proto file which has a bidirectional stream between the client and the server. Does this mean that the client and server can send and receive messages arbitrarily? I'm more confused about the server side. How can the server send data over this bidirectional stream arbitrarily? What would be the trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: A stream means you can send multiple message. Bidirectional means you can send multiple messages in both directions. There is no way for a server to call a client.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#bidirectional-streaming-rpc):

> In a bidirectional streaming RPC, again the call is initiated by the
>   client calling the method and the server receiving the client
>   metadata, method name, and deadline. Again the server can choose to
>   send back its initial metadata or wait for the client to start sending
>   requests.
>
> What happens next depends on the application, as the client and server
>   can read and write in any order - the streams operate completely
>   independently. [...]

This means: the client would establish the connection to the server and you'd then have a connection on wich both parties can read/write.